# Spring Security[3.1.0] public(unprotected) endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring 3.1.0 and I want to be able to access some routes without authentication. However, after using the code below, the browser opens a small login window, where I need to add a username and password.

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
            .requestMatchers("/login", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .httpBasic(withDefaults())
        .anonymous(a -> a.disable());
    return http.build();
  }
```

This is how the code will look when I use spring security 2.x . How to migrate the code below using spring 3.1.0?

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login", "/home").permitAll()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have whitelisted/unsecured some swagger endpoints previously using below code, this should work for you.
Also make sure priority of this Bean `SecurityFilterChain` is set if there are more than one Bean for above class.

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
            auth.requestMatchers("/v3/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll();
            auth.requestMatchers("/login", "/home").permitAll();
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
        }).httpBasic();
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your code if it extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/login")
            .antMatchers("/home");
}
```